# PHP preg_match specific field value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to get the id or the name of a field that keeps changing its value.

Example:

I have these fields in my form:

```
<input type="text" id="94245" name="94245" value="">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="">
<input type="text" id="status" name="status" value="">
```

And I want to get the ID or the name of the first field, but it keeps changing, like:

```
<input type="text" id="52644" name="52644" value="">
<input type="text" id="44231" name="44231" value="">
<input type="text" id="94831" name="94831" value="">
```

The pattern is that is always a 5 number value.

I've tried this, but no success:

```
preg_match('/(\d)id=\s*([0-9]{5})\s*(\d+)/', $html, $fieldId);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `DOM`?

Comment: Can you modify the code to add something like `onclick=` or `onchange=` events to those inputs? Can you add another field to your form, like a hidden input?

Comment: It's an external site. Can't change the code from creating the form.

Comment: Will other fields come with a numeric name, or only the first one?

Comment: Might you try something like iterating over the post data like `foreach $_POST as $key => $value`? Since you state only the first field has a numeric name, just check that `$key` is numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/\bid\s*=\s*"(\d{5})"/', $html, $fieldId);
```

- The escape sequence for a word boundary is `\b`, not `\d`.
- There's no reason to use a capture group around `\b`, since it's a zero-length match.
- You didn't match the double quotes around the ID.
- You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` to match digits.
- There's no `\d+` after the ID, I don't know what that's for in your regexp.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to simply have omitted the quotation marks. Otherwise, your regex is sound. You may want to place \s's around the equal sign, just in case:

```
if (preg_match('/\\s*name\\s*=\\s*"([0-9]{5})"/', $html, $gregs)) {
    $fieldId = $gregs[1];
}
```

As you can see I have also changed the searched attribute from `id` to `name`. In your example they're equal, but the value being sent will be the one specified by `name`.

If this name-rewriting anti-scraping strategy is ever applied to more fields, you can first get an array of fields by looking for "]*>" (even though [you shouldn't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)), and then use `array_map` to extract each of them to a string with the tag name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use brute force. Next file, **numeric_name1.php**, sends the form, where the first field has a numeric name. The second file, **numeric_name2.php**, iterates all numbers until it finds one that exists in $_POST. Here they are:

**numeric_name1.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="numeric_name2.php">
      <input type="text" id="94245" name="94245" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="status" name="status" value="" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit this form"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**numeric_name2.php**

```
<?php
for ( $i = 0; $i < 99999; $i++ )      // TRY ALL NUMBERS WITH 5 DIGITS.
{ $num = sprintf( "%05d",$i );        // EXPAND $I TO A STRING WITH 5 DIGITS.
  if ( isSet( $_POST[ $num ] ) )      // IF THIS NUMERIC NAME EXISTS...
     { echo "The name is = " . $num;
       break;                         // STOP WHEN FOUND.
     }
}
?>
```

To test this code, create two text files, use the given names, copy-paste the code, open your browser and run "localhost/numeric_name1.php".