# Write to TXT file with length delimited data

Tags: php, fwrite, spaces, delimited

I'm trying to write to a text file on php, the fields need to be a certain length for each one. 
Order Number is 10 characters long, order name is 5 characters, telephone is 12 characters long.

Ex:

```
12345    1234 123456789123
```

If I try:

```
fwrite('text.txt', '12345', 10);
fwrite('text.txt', '1234', 5);
fwrite('text.txt', '12346789123', 12);
```

I get: 
123451234123456789123

How can I tell it to add the spaces to the specific size I need in each field.

Comment: http://php.nt/sprintf

Comment: http://php.net/sprintf

Comment: Or more directly: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fprintf.php

Comment: Example of sprintf = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790885/php-preg-match-specific-field-value/30791308#30791308

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
fwrite('text.txt', str_pad('12345', 10, " "));
fwrite('text.txt', str_pad('1234', 5, " "));
fwrite('text.txt', str_pad('12346789123', 12, " "));
```